# Why I get params as nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that I submit using jQuery:

```
<form data-type="html" novalidate="novalidate" id="free_circuit_form" class="new_experiment" action="/en/experiments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+0BPI4JbryN/WVCGrA0OxZNIteXb0p01XZJsxVtW9qYFIxt0EgQ6OJ2rDpaTmQwlVPe9a/qlwEteHvnjWbysOw==" />

<input type="hidden" id="experiment_not_signed_in_circuit_data" name="experiment[not_signed_in_circuit_data]"/>
</form>
```

but when I access `params` inside the controller, I got it `nil`! Shouldn't `params` contain all parameters I sent with form?

In the experiment controller, I permit the parameters as:

```
def experiment_params
    params.require(:experiment).permit(: not_signed_in_circuit_data, :title, :circuit, :intro_text, :public, :meta_description, :thumbnail => [:data], :descriptions_attributes => [:id, :data, :title, :position], :circuits_attributes => [:id, :data, :title, :position, :circuit_types])
  end
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

Here is the server log for request after I tried to use the application controller to place the action in:

```
Started POST "/en/not_signed_in_circuit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-12 18:38:24 +0300
Processing by ApplicationController#not_signed_in_circuit as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tNwIjklA9Ic3u7jOpMJUSPPd8lDmKkZTppG0UvQuBchKv1zZ2R9hnNVJ5t6bVlaoNGL63sddGy2lHSF09sRfVQ==", "experiment"=>{"not_signed_in_circuit_data"=>"{\"public\":false,\"title\":\"abc\",\"circuits\":[{\"circuit\":\"0\",\"text\":\"\"}]}"}, "locale"=>"en"}
```

I can see the parameters in the log, but inside the action, `params` is `nil`

Comment: Have you checked if there are naming conflicts with `params` (i.e. a variable or method having the name, `params`, aside from... `params` itself)?

Comment: `params` it self is 'nil`!

Comment: see the development log when you post to the controller.See params which get posted

Comment: kindly see the EDIT above

Comment: Are you accessing `experiment_params` or `params` directly. The params posted to the controller seem correct and your `expirement_params` also seems correct. Do you manipulate params in any way before you get this error?

Comment: Ah! accessing `experiment_params` works fine, but why `params` return nil ?!

Answer (score 0):

Your form is a bit strange, you probably don't use the Rails form helpers like `form_for`. But actually you have a naming issue.

All your form input elements should be named according to your model like :

- experiment[something]
- experiment[somethingelse]
- experiment[anotherthing]

In your case there are only 3 inputs:
`utf8`, `authenticity_token` and `experiment[not_signed_in_circuit_data]`

So there is actually only one param that is linked to your model.

You can access this param in your controller with : `params[:experiment][:not_signed_in_circuit_data]`. So this is normal you don't have access to the others params linked to experiment model (like title, circuit)

What is funny is that, when we have a look to the logs, we can see extra params under `params[:experiment][:not_signed_in_circuit_data]`. You may access them like this : `params[:experiment][:not_signed_in_circuit_data][:title]` or `params[:experiment][:not_signed_in_circuit_data][:public]`. There seem to be an extra layer of nesting..

I suggest you simplify your form and make every input field with a name like `experiment[title]` etc ...